# How to repeat a function a random number of times with an upper limit on the random number in bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, random

I am trying to repeatedly run a python script a random number of times using bash. However, to avoid running the script a massive amount of times I want to place an upper limit on the amount of times it can run. Currently I am using the 'modulo' operator to return a remainder and then using that as a string when performing a loop:

```
 #!/bin/bash

RANGE=1000

number=$RANDOM
let "number %= $RANGE"

for run in {1..$number}
do
  python script.py
done
```

The random number works (i.e. `$number` is a random number between 1-1000), but the problem is that this only seems to be running the script once, no matter what the random number is.

What might the problem be?

Comment: You can't use a variable in `{1..1000}` construction..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
for run in {1..$number}
```

Since variables are not allowed (expanded) inside range `{..}` thus causing your loop to **run only once** no matter what is the value of `$number`.

Use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

range=1000
number=$((RANDOM % range))

for ((run=1; run <= number; run++)); do
   python script.py
done
```

Comment: I've removed my other two comments.  You might as well not evaluate `number % range` on each iteration - or run the risk of doing so.  I think I'd go with `range=1000;number=$(($RANDOM % $range))` and then `for ((run=1; run <= number; run++))` or equivalent.